# How to center continuous raster layer by subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation using QGIS raster calculator?

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, raster-calculator

I'm trying to extrapolate a spatial model to a map in QGIS using the raster calculator. The model predicts the value of a pixel given the environmental conditions at this location (e.g. elevation, slope, ect.). Hence, each explanatory variable is a raster layer. For the model I centered my covariates by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. Now I want to do the same to my raster layers. As trivial as this seems, I didn't manage to do so. I tried (among similar attempts - like changing upper case, etc.):

```
(my.raster-mean(my.raster))/sd(my.raster)
```

The calculator tells me the expression is valid, however, mean() and sd() don't work.

And I could not find a site with the built-in functions for the raster calculator.

Comment: Seeing as mean and standard deviation are constant for a given raster can you insert the real values from the raster properties?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing now, however, since I have multiple layers it would be convenient if I could do this somehow within raster calculator. Also I'm a bit reluctant to copy-paste solutions as it seems always prone to errors. I just figured there would be some built-in function for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raster calculator is a wrong tool to do that because it is for map algebra. The **mean(my.raster)** or **sd(my.raster)** expressions return **my_raster** (not the constants that you are hoping). For this reason, your expression **(my.raster-mean(my.raster))/sd(my.raster)** will be evaluated to 0 for each pixel.

At the below image you can see that any "function" it will be "valid" and it will return the same raster.

[image]

As it was pointed out by Michael, you need to evaluate mean and standard deviation constants first by other methods. You can do that with GDAL-python, PyQGIS or R (with rgdal o raster libraries).

Next, one example with PyQGIS:

[image]

For the complete process, you need to adapt this solution:

[Qgis raster calculator not giving output](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139290/qgis-raster-calculator-not-giving-output/139299#139299)

**Editing Note 1**:

The complete solution is this:

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

layer = iface.activeLayer()
entries = []

# Define band1
band1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
band1.ref = 'band@1'
band1.raster = layer
band1.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( band1 )

renderer = layer.renderer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
extent = layer.extent()

stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All,extent, 0)

myMean = stats.mean
myStdDev = stats.stdDev

myFormula = '(band@1 -' + str(myMean) +')/' + str(myStdDev)

print "mean = ", myMean 

print "stdev = ", myStdDev

# Process calculation with input extent and resolution
calc = QgsRasterCalculator( myFormula, 
                            '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/outputfile.tif', 
                            'GTiff',
                            layer.extent(), 
                            layer.width(), 
                            layer.height(), 
                            entries )

calc.processCalculation()
```

It works nicely.

**Editing Note 2:**

This is the complete code with R (**Benedikt Gehr** approach and **RobertH** approach). It is really simple and the results are the same (see image below with Value Tool Plugin).

```
setwd('pyqgis_data') #where is my_raster
library(raster)
my_raster<-raster('utah_demUTM2.tif')
#Benedikt Gehr approach
centered_raster<-(my_raster-cellStats(my_raster,mean))/(cellStats(my_raster,sd))
#RobertH approach
centered_raster2 <- scale(my_raster)
writeRaster(centered_raster, 'centered_raster.tif', format='GTiff',overwrite=TRUE)
writeRaster(centered_raster2, 'centered_raster2.tif', format='GTiff',overwrite=TRUE)
```

[image]

However, these approaches require the **rgdal** library installed. Sometimes, Windows users have problems with its installation.

Comment: the complete process solution for R using the "raster" package is very simple: `centered_raster<-(my_raster-cellStats(my_raster,mean))/(cellStats(my_raster,sd)` Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome. You can see my complete solution with PyQGIS too (I edit my answer). The advantage is that you can load the output raster directly in QGIS.

Comment: In R it can actually be simpler than that: `centered_raster <- scale(my_raster)`

Comment: @RobertH I know that R is really amazing and it was one of my sugestions. For this reason, I edited my answer to include both approaches.Thank you.