# Alternatives to QGIS raster calculator?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, raster-calculator

I am using QGIS 3 on a Mac. I have a large raster (bfd.tif size is 26000, 31800) that I'm trying to apply a calculation to. When I use the default raster calculator in QGIS 3 I get a raster back with every pixel the same value. When I try to use the Geoprocessing r.mapcalc I get "env python3 no such file or directory".

I'm following this tutorial [Creating Shaded Relief in Blender](https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/creating-shaded-relief-in-blender/) so in order to have a height map that works with Blender each pixel value needs to be an integer. I'm using this formula to stretch the values evenly from my min -2.06 to my max 1615.48.

```
raster_out=( bfd + 2.06 ) / ( 1615.48 + 2.06 ) * 65535
```

There is a question here that looks like an alternative but I'm not sure how to run this code or how to manipulate it for my purpose. [QGIS Raster Calculator Not Giving Output](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139290/qgis-raster-calculator-not-giving-output) Where can I learn about this method?

And fixing environment variables for QGIS 3 and Python might help me but this question has no answers. [QGIS 3 env Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709569/mac-qgis-3-0-env-python3-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Do you have `SAGA 2.3.2` (GUI version) in QGIS folder? It's Grid Calculator can handle large file, and you can assign *Data Type* (such as `unsigned 1/2/4 byte integer` simultaneously.

Comment: I don't have SAGA. I'm looking into installing it now

Comment: Then you might be on Mac OS, sorry I do not know if SAGA GUI works on it.

Comment: qgis saga integration works fine on Mac OS, but I'd recommend at least QGIS 3.0.1 if using KyngChaos build. I have saga_gui working but this seems to be via homebrew (saga-gis-lts)